# How to find splits in data so that each split has equal weighting according to function f

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, statistics

I have a weight function f that outputs a numeric weighting for a sample s. I also have an ordered set of samples S where the weight of each sample s in set S varies greatly.

How can I create n splitting points so that each split is weighted approximately the same? What kind of methodology, algorithms or models could I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A classic optimization problem! You can use Linear Programming/Optimization to find a good split. Every of the **n** samples **s** $\in S$ has weight **f(s)** and we want to divide them into **m** folds. You can use a trick to linearize the L1 objective or you can use Quadratic Programming for a L2 objective function. The Quadratic Programming model is easier to define in this case. Let's define $x_{ij}$ as a binary decision to put sample **i** in fold **j** and **$\mu$** is the ideal, mean weight per fold. Then this is our objective function:

min $\sum_{j=1}^m(\sum_{i=1}^nx_{ij}f(i)-\mu)^2$

Under the following constraints:

$\sum_{j=1}^mx_{ij}=1$ for all $i\in \{1..n\}$ to ensure exactly one assignment per sample

$x_{ij} \in \{0, 1\}$ to turn it into binary decision varibales

Depending on the size of your dataset and the solver you use this can be a heavy optimization, but there are a lot of greedy heuristics that will get you close fairly fast.